# How to know the sender in KVO?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift, key-value-observing

When I use KVO, I can use the change parameter of function observeValueForKeyPath(...) to know the value. But when there are more than one button added the observer, how can I know which button is changed?

For example as follow:

```
check1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "cell.state", 
    options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old,
    context: nil)
check2.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "cell.state", 
    options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old,
    context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject: AnyObject,
    change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> {

    if keyPath == "cell.state" {
        // I can get the value as follow, but how to know thevalue which button of?
        if change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]?.boolValue == true {
            self.isChecked = true
        } else {
            self.IsChecked = false
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ofObject:` parameter is the object whose property has been changed.
In Swift, you can use an optional cast (`as?`) to verify that the object is
of the appropriate type, and then compare it against your buttons:

```
if let button = ofObject as? NSButton {
    if button == check1 {
        // Checkbox 1 ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question: why you use 'ofObject as? NSButton'? I have tried to use 'ofObject as? NSButton', the xcode invoked an error.

Comment: @cck: You have tagged the question with both iOS and OS X, so I have *guessed* that check1 and check2 are NSButtons. Perhaps clarify: Is this an iOS or OS X project? How are check1 and check2 declared?

Comment: Actually, it's an checkbox in os x project. It's correct in my project, I just want to know that why you use 'as?' symbol, because I had tried 'ofObject as Nsbuuton' which didn't work.

Comment: `if let` is an "optional binding" and that can only used with an optional expression on the right hand side, e.g. the "optional cast" `as?`. – You could also write `let button = ofObject as NSButton` without the `if`. But then it would crash if the sender is *not* a NSButton.

Comment: @cck: Is your question answered now?